# submitting data from contactform7 wordpress plugin through curl to api into db

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin on my wordpress website - which is contactform7. I also have an extension / plugin called submissions (this some how gets all the info from my contact form and puts it into my database automatically.

On my previous website using a html form i was able to submit the data through an api using CURL.

I am trying to merge the two together so it works with contactform7, how ever it's not working, the form doesn't give a response and no errors are shown.

Any advice would be great.

**Original code from submissions.php**

```
 $additional_fields = apply_filters('wpcf7s_submission_fields', $submission['fields'], $submission['form_id']);
             if (!empty($additional_fields)) {



                 foreach ($additional_fields as $name => $value) {
                     if (!empty($value)) {
                         add_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf7s_posted-' . $name, $value);
                     }
                 }
             }
```

**Original submitform.php for my previous HTML form**

```
<?php


$contaactcode=isset($_REQUEST['countrycode']) ? $_REQUEST['countrycode'] : '';
$countryname= isset($_REQUEST['phone']) ? $_REQUEST['phone'] : '';


$service_url = 'http://api.MYwebsite.com/addData';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data = array(

    'title' => isset($_REQUEST['title']) ? $_REQUEST['title'] : '',
    'Condidate'  => isset($_REQUEST['name']) ? $_REQUEST['name'] : '' ,
    'lastname'  => isset($_REQUEST['lastname']) ? $_REQUEST['lastname'] : '',
    'Email'  => isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? $_REQUEST['email'] : '',
    'whyvisa'  => isset($_REQUEST['whyvisa']) ? $_REQUEST['whyvisa'] : '',
    'visatype'  => isset($_REQUEST['visatype']) ? $_REQUEST['visatype'] : '',
    'date_day'  => isset($_REQUEST['day']) ? $_REQUEST['day'] : '',
    'date_month'  => isset($_REQUEST['month']) ? $_REQUEST['month'] : '',
    'date_year'  => isset($_REQUEST['year']) ? $_REQUEST['year'] : '' ,
    'Contact'  => $contaactcode." ".$countryname,
    'nationality'  => isset($_REQUEST['nationality']) ? $_REQUEST['nationality'] : '',
    'occupation'  => isset($_REQUEST['occupation']) ? $_REQUEST['occupation'] : '',
    'postalcode'  => isset($_REQUEST['postalcode']) ? $_REQUEST['postalcode'] : '',
    'destinationcountry'  =>  isset($_REQUEST['menu-country']) ? $_REQUEST['menu-country'] : '',
    'residingcountry'  => isset($_REQUEST['countrylist']) ? $_REQUEST['countrylist'] : '',
    'address'  => isset($_REQUEST['address']) ? $_REQUEST['address'] : '',
    'education'  => isset($_REQUEST['education']) ? $_REQUEST['education'] : '',
    'require_time'  => isset($_REQUEST['helpwithvisa']) ? $_REQUEST['helpwithvisa'] : '',
    'applydate'  => date("Y-m-d"),
    'add_info'  => isset($_REQUEST['massage']) ? $_REQUEST['massage'] : '',
    'StillInthisEmployment' => isset($_REQUEST['StillInthisEmployment']) ? $_REQUEST['StillInthisEmployment'] : '',
    'exprienceduration'  => isset($_REQUEST['exprienceduration']) ? $_REQUEST['exprienceduration'] : '' ,
    'leadfrom'  => isset($_REQUEST['lead']) ? $_REQUEST['lead'] : '' ,
    'apikey' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'crmtype' => 'mainUk'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($curl_response);
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
}
```

?>

**UPDATED submissions.php file to insert the fields data into the API**

```
$service_url = 'http://MYwebsiteSITE.com/addData';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);

    $postfields = array();
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $postfields[] = stripslashes($key) . "=" . stripslashes(urlencode($value));
        }
        /* post data to curl in urlencoded format */
        $curl_post_data  = join("&", $postfields);
        //echo $curl_post_data;

        // You may need to add the apikey and crmtype if they are not part of form as below. Uncomment the line below. 
        $curl_post_data  = $curl_post_data.'&apikey=XXXXXXXXX&crmtype=mainUK';
        //echo $curl_post_data;


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
```